# Insert Data Into SQL Table using txt file

Tags: mysql, insert, phpmyadmin

I have a txt file with lots of SQL insert statements.  I was trying to copy it and paste it into phpMyAdmin.

But obviously the string is too large and is not pasted there.

Does anyone know how insert this data on the database from the txt file?

Comment: Can you run `mysql` from the command line?

Comment: I don't know how to do that but I could.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin has an Import feature, just click on the Import tab and select the text file.

Comment: @timgavin: I think the import feature may have a size limit also.

Comment: Using PHPMyAdmin to import the file caused a maximum execution time error.

Comment: If you have access to a terminal on the server, then you can do `mysql -u user -p dbname < file.txt`

Comment: If you can't do as @RocketHazmat suggests, try Big Dump: http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/. I've used it before and it works well.

Comment: You said the text file has lots of INSERT statements, so one other thing to try - if possible - is to just break up the text file into smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin can import your file. If the size exceeds PHP limit for upload, you can use this phpMyAdmin feature:

http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html?highlight=uploaddir#cfg_UploadDir

Answer (score 0):

as @timgavin say, PHPMyAdmin has an Import feature, so you can upload your file.

But as you know, php has upload size limit. So if the file is too large, you have too use mysql cli client.

`mysql -u user -p dbname < file.txt`

is the correct answer.